# Combinations in sets

Tags: combinations

Say a set $X=\{A,B,C,D\}$

How many proper subsets does it have? And how do you determine this?
I thought that it was 14 due to adding up combinations of:

$4C_1 + 4C_2 + 4C_3$   so $4+6+4=14$ possibilities

However, it turns out to be $15$ in the answer of my textbook.

What is the $15^{th}$ possibility? and also how do you determine the pattern for these kinds of sets?
(for example set $Y=\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ with $6$ values and set $Z=\{A,B,C\}$ with $3$ values)

Comment: How can $A$ be in also $A$? Names are problematic.

Comment: Oh, Some error. Thanks for mentioning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the empty set, which is also a proper subset.

To form a subset, each of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ can be either chosen or not chosen as an element. So you have 2 choices for each of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. There are totally $2\times 2\times 2\times 2=2^4$ choices. Excluding $X$ itself, there are $2^4-1$ proper subsets.

Comment: Why the downvote???

Comment: Confused me too.

Comment: Hold on, if a subset isn't a proper subset, does it still include the empty set. If no, why?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperSubset.html.  The empty set is a proper subset, $X$ itself is not. That's why we only have $2^4-1$ proper subsets, as Mickey mentioned.